# Python: word count from WordCloud

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am using WordCloud on a body of text, and I would like to see the actual counts for each word in the cloud. I can see the weighted frequencies using .words_ but I was wondering if there is an easy way to see the actual counts?

```
# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white").generate(text)
wordfreq = wordcloud.words_
```

Edit: the reason I would like to be able to see the word counts from the WordCloud (versus just finding word counts from the text myself) is because  WordCloud includes phrases (collocations) as well as single words in its analysis. So, for example, a count of "water resources" would appear, as well as a count of the word "water" when it does not appear in "water resources." WordCloud also appears to add instances of words that appear in plural form to the count of the word as a singular (e.g. counting "water resources" in the count of "water resource").

Comment: Simplest way is to provide the frequencies and also add them to the word, then you need to build a list of tuples, each containing a word (suffixed with the frequency as a string) and its frequency, then call `WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies(freqs)`.

Comment: Do you mean that a word will repeat several times in the generated cloud?

Comment: Each word only has one frequency. Adding that frequency to the word Before it is displayed doesn’t change its frequency.

Comment: WordCloud doesn't do anything magic. It just counts the words in your own text and derives the frequency from that. If you want to know those frequencies, you don't need to make a word cloud first; you can count them right away.

Comment: WordCloud does seem to do a little beyond counting the words in the text. It includes phrases (collocations) and also appears to add instances of words that appear in plural form to the count of the word as a singular (e.g. counting "water resources" in the count of "water resource"). I could write code to do this myself, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to see these counts just using WordCloud.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `WordCloud().process_text(text)`:

```
>>> WordCloud().process_text('penn penn penn penn penn state state state state uni uni uni college college university states vice president vice president vice president vice president vice president vice president vice president')
{'penn': 5, 'state': 5, 'uni': 3, 'college': 2, 'university': 1, 'vice president': 7}
```

Notice that it combines "states" into the "state" count and also counts "vice president" as a bigram.

Comment: I have text in data frame, how to get word cloud count in bar char

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, you can also sort the words by count as follows:

```
words = wordcloud.process_text("yay yay yay nay nay okay okaay")
sorted_words = sorted(words.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
sorted_words.reverse()
```